# What type of function is $y=x^{-1}$?

Tags: functions

What type of function is $y=x^{-1}$? It's not a polynomial I think because they should be positive exponents, so what are these functions called?

Comment: [Rational function.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_function)

Comment: It's graph is a hyperbola

Answer (score 2):

$$y=x^{-1}$$

So $y=x^{-1}$ is not a polynomial , because $-1 \notin \mathbb Z^+_0$.

$$y=\frac{1}{x}$$

$$y=\frac{h(x)}{g(x)}$$

Where $h(x)=1$ and $g(x)=x$.

So for $x \neq 0 $ ,  $y$ is a **Rational function**.